# How to integrate a custom ISelectionProvider with Eclipse enabledWhen expressions?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, selection

I have a custom graphical EditorPart in a Eclipse RCP application.

It sets a custom ISelectionProvider in the createPartControl(..) method:

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    // [snip] 
    getSite().setSelectionProvider((ISelectionProvider)model.getSelection());
}
```

I have two ViewParts listening to selection changes via the ISelectionService. They get notified when the selection in the EditorPart changes. So far so good.

Now I've added a handler using the following XML:

> ```
> <handlerclass="my.custom.Handler" commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete">
>     <enabledWhen>
>         <count value="+"/>
>     </enabledWhen>
> </handler>
> ```

If the selection in the EditPart contains > 0 elements, this should enable the handler my.custom.Handler, but it doesn't.

It is, however enabled if the selection provided by built-in selection providers changes to > 0 element (i.e. those provided by JFace viewers).

Any hint how to integrate a custom implementation of ISelectionProvider with the expression framework used in the handler declaration?

Comment: Could you post your implementation of ISelectionProvider? I.e. the class that is returned at `model.getSelection()
`I suspect the problem to be in your implementation of ISelectionProvider.

Answer (score 1):

enabledWhen can contain any expression. You need to specify that you want the selection variable there. See here for an example: http://eclipse-tips.com/tutorials/1-actions-vs-commands?start=1